# How detect that update callback is of the target sortable in sortable widget

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

I am working on a functionality that includes sortable jQuery widget. Sortable includes two (or more) lists and users can move items from one to another. Everything is working fine as far as UI functionality goes. However, I need to be able to execute different logic in update callback on target and source sortable.

In my case I can't just simply rely on id's as they are dynamically generated. I tried different ways of comparing **event.target** and **ui.item.parent()** but I am still having difficulties to figure out which is the source and which is destination.

I'm probably misunderstanding the mechanics of these callbacks available in each one of them and was trying to find an example of how to do it properly. Or any other suggestion.

Thanks.

Comment: "Sortable includes two (or more) lists" does this mean that the items being sorted itself is a list..? can you provide sample `html` markup and the code you've tried..?

Answer (score 0):

U can add an attribute to your dom initially and then update accordingly when they traverse through your lists.

Something like

`$(ui.item).attr("item-source", "list1")` for setting a value initially and then `$(ui.item).attr("item-source", "list2")` for updating.

If you are making use of HTML5 u can make use of something similar like [data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes)